# How to block all incoming calls?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to block all incoming calls for a while? Or at least can I put my phone into silent programmatically?

Comment: From a user's perspective this is a terrible thing to do. I would be careful to avoid your app if you are kind enough to name it here.

Answer (score 3):

No. Simply you cannot do that. There is no public API is available to do that. Your app will be in sandbox mode. You cannot access them in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be done from **iOS 10 and above** using the [CallKit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit) framework upto a certain amount. The numbers we provide can be blocked. If you want to block all incoming calls, just use Airplane mode.

> The CallKit framework provides programmatic access to VoIP functionality, as well as call blocking and identification.